# Mysql not using index in LEFT JOIN when joined column used in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause, indexing

I've been puzzling around this problem in mySQL 5.0.51a for quite a while now:

When using LEFT JOIN to join a table AND using a column of the joined table in the WHERE clause, mySQL fails to use the primary index of the joined table in the JOIN, even FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY) fails.

- If no column of the joined table is in the WHERE clause, everything works fine.
- If the GROUP BY is removed, the index is also used.

Yet I need both of them.

Faulty:
(in my special case up to 1000 secs of exec time)

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_contract co
LEFT JOIN tbl_customer cu ON cu.customer_id = co.customer_id
WHERE cu.marketing_allowed = 1 AND co.marketing_allowed = 1
GROUP BY cu.id
ORDER BY cu.name ASC
```

Working, but not solving my problems:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_contract co
LEFT JOIN tbl_customer cu ON cu.customer_id = co.customer_id
GROUP BY co.id
```

Table structures (transcribed, as the real tables are more complex)

```
tbl_contract: 
id: INT(11) PRIMARY
customer_id: INT(11)
marketing_allowed: TINYINT(1)

tbl_customer:
customer_id: INT(11) PRIMARY
marketing_allowed: TINYINT(1)
```

mySQL EXPLAIN notices PRIMARY as possible key when joining, but doesn't use it.

There has been one solution:

```
SELECT (...)
HAVING cu.marketing_allowed = 1
```

Solves the problem *BUT* we use the query in other contexts, where we can only select ONE column in the whole statement, but HAVING needs the marketing_allowed column to be selected in the SELECT-Statement.

I also noticed, that running ANALYZE TABLE on the desired tables will make mySQL 5.5.8 on my local system do the right thing, but I cannot always assure that ANALYZE has been run right before the statement. Anyways, this solution does not work under mySQL 5.0.51a on our productive server. :(

Is there a special rule in mySQL which I didn't notice? Why are LEFT JOIN indexes not used if columns appear in the WHERE clause? Why can't I force them?

Thx in advance,

René

[EDIT]

Thanks to some replies I could optimize the query using an INNER JOIN, but unfortunately, though seeming absolutely fine, mySQL still rejects to use an index when using an ORDER BY clause, as I found out:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_contract co
INNER JOIN tbl_customer cu ON cu.customer_id = co.customer_id AND cu.marketing_allowed = 1
WHERE cu.marketing_allowed = 1
ORDER BY cu.name ASC
```

If you leave the ORDER BY out, mySQL will use the index correctly.
I have removed the GROUP BY as it has no relevance in the example.

[EDIT2]

FORCING Indexes does not help, as well. So, the question is: Why does mySQL not use an index for joining, as the ORDER BY is executed AFTER joining and reducing the result set by a WHERE clause ? This should usually not influence joining...

Comment: How do you know that "mySQL fails to use the primary index"?  Have you inspected the output of `EXPLAIN`?  Could you include it in your question?

Comment: please share table structure.

Comment: Hi, yes, I used EXPLAIN heavily, I will modify my request after the lunch break ;)

Comment: Just edited it... obviously, the GROUP BY I am using influences the behaviour, didn't notice that before... Thx for your help in advance.

Comment: I just found out that my ORDER BY cu.customer_name ASC at the end is also a factor that prevents it. But ORDER BY is always executed after WHERE and therefore should not influence using an index on a join, should it?

Comment: This article might be useful for you to understand JOINS [http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p5.php](http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p5.php)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking, but

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_contract co
LEFT JOIN tbl_customer cu ON cu.customer_id = co.customer_id
WHERE cu.marketing_allowed = 1 AND co.marketing_allowed = 1
```

will not do an outer join (because of `cu.marketing_allowed = 1`).

You probably meant to use:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_contract co
   LEFT JOIN tbl_customer cu 
        ON cu.customer_id = co.customer_id
       AND cu.marketing_allowed = 1 
WHERE co.marketing_allowed = 1
```

Comment: As mentioned in the other post, I then have a problem sorting out the contracts where no customer was associated to. WHERE cu.customer_id IS NOT NULL will lead to the same problem that mySQL does not use the index

Comment: @RenéHerzog: apparently you don't want an outer join, so why do you use one?

Comment: Okay, I just only know this one, I am already researching, what kind of join would be best?

Comment: @RenéHerzog: apparently you only want `JOIN` (which is an inner join). `LEFT JOIN` is an outer join

Comment: Hi, yeah, thx. I found that out and use the INNER JOIN now, being able to not use a WHERE clause extension. Unfortunately, this makes mySQL not use the possible index (I created a combined index for cu.marketing_allowed and cu.customer_id - EXPLAIN shows Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort...

Comment: I just found out that my ORDER BY cu.customer_name ASC at the end is also a factor that prevents it. But ORDER BY is always executed after WHERE and therefore should not influence using an index on a join, should it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble. MySQL optimizer is not using indexes while using JOIN with conditions. I changed my SQL statement from JOIN to subqueries :

```
SELECT
    t1.field1,
    t1.field2,
    ...
    (SELECT
        t2.field3
        FROM table2 t2
        WHERE t2.fieldX=t1.fieldX
    ) AS field3,
    (SELECT
        t2.field4
        FROM table2 t2
        WHERE t2.fieldX=t1.fieldX
    ) AS field4,
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.fieldZ='valueZ'
ORDER BY t1.sortedField
```

This request is much more complicated but as indexes are used, it is also much more faster.

You could also use `STRAIGHT_JOIN` but performance is better with above query. Here's a comparison for by DB with 100k rows in table1 and 20k in table2 :

- 0.00s using above query
- 0.10s using `STRAIGHT_JOIN`
- 0.30 using `JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried multiple condition on JOIN clause?

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_contract co
LEFT JOIN tbl_customer cu ON cu.customer_id = co.customer_id AND cu.marketing_allowed = 1
WHERE co.marketing_allowed = 1
```

Comment: Hi, yes. This was my first thought. Actually, I then have to sort out the lines that have no joined customer, as he has forbidden to get marketing information. - This leads to WHERE ... AND cu.customer_id IS NOT NULL which also creates the problem that the INDEX is not used. :(

Comment: Im afraid I didn't get "sort out the lines that have no joined customer" If you meant elimination, I am sure you would've used INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN.. please explain a bit more

Comment: Perhaps I am on the totally wrong path. Perhaps a different JOIN type will solve my problem. I'll check and report, thx so far.

Comment: I now use an INNER JOIN and can prevent the WHERE clause part, but unfortunately mySQL still refuses to use an index. I just don't know what to do here :(

Comment: I just found out that my ORDER BY cu.customer_name ASC at the end is also a factor that prevents it. But ORDER BY is always executed after WHERE and therefore should not influence using an index on a join, should it?

Comment: Using index(es) in ORDER clause is always a good idea as It significantly improves performance. But you shouldn't be using cu at all after LEFT JOIN because Not all the records could have corresponding record from cu table. Please Update your SQL.

Comment: Yep, that's why I am now using an INNER JOIN. All results have no null values on this column. As ORDER BY is exeuted after WHERE, IMHO it should not prevent the join from using an index for joining - this is the current problem. An index for the order is another problem I can solve later...

Comment: Please provide your current SQL

Comment: It is the one in the post, T edited it.: SELECT *
FROM tbl_contract co
LEFT JOIN tbl_customer cu ON cu.customer_id = co.customer_id
WHERE cu.marketing_allowed = 1 AND co.marketing_allowed = 1
GROUP BY cu.id
ORDER BY cu.name ASC

Comment: Yeah, That IS wrong. As I said before, and most of these guys have mentioned, you cannot refer "cu" anywhere (except in another JOIN) after using it on LEFT JOIN. So, remove your query, use this one primarily:
SELECT *
FROM tbl_contract co
INNER JOIN tbl_customer cu ON cu.customer_id = co.customer_id AND cu.marketing_allowed = 1
WHERE co.marketing_allowed = 1.

Now, explain what is wrong with the result set. No need to worry about index @ the moment.

Comment: Yep, if I remove the ORDER BY, everything is fine - so far... Unfortunately, we provide a sorting functionality which refers to this column, or other joned columns - is there any common solution to sort without the disadvantages of ORDER BY? (Except completely rearranging the query every time the sorting column changes) - Thanks anyways so far.